# Login loop kali linux (kalli-rolling)

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I’m having problems with logging in on Kali Linux. After I did apt-get update & apt-get upgrade I rebooted the system. When I go to the login, I type “root” for username and my password and it logs me out immediately. I can log with a different user.

On the main screen I press Ctrl+Alt+F2, and I can log in with “root” username and password. I try dpkg --configure -a and then apt-get update and apt-get upgrade, but nothing. That happens when I remove NVidia drivers with apt-get remove --purge nvidia*, because I’m stuck on the “Oh no! Something has gone wrong.” and “A problem has occurred and the system can’t recover. Please log out and try again.” errors.

After removing the NVidia drivers, I cannot login as root. I can login with a different user, and when I type su and password for “root” I don’t have a problem. I tried chown -R root:root /root, but nothing. I tried to install dkms but it says that it is already installed.

Comment: No one would be able to answer this unless you can narrow it down a bit. Search `/var/log/` for recent errors and update your question with the problems you find.

Comment: In syslog there is nothing suspicious because the date is old. But in user.log and messages there is many log like this: kali gnome-software-service.desktop[1158]  17:46:17:0845 as filed to rescan: Failed to parse /usr/share/applications/kali-dhcpig.desktop file: cannot process file of type application/x-desktop. And instead kali-dhcpig.desktop there is more logs with different applications.

Answer (score 0):

please try to use this command to deal with it. I hope it can fix

`apt-get install kali-defaults kali-root-login desktop-base kde-plasma-desktop` (for KDE)

`apt-get install kali-defaults kali-root-login desktop-base xfce4 xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-goodies` (for XFCE)